# How to make a label sticked in rectangle in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uitouch

Hi there I drag a label with a touch into a hollow rectangle, now I want to make the label stick with a rectangle and should not be movable with any user interaction, How can I make my label stuck with a rectangle? My labels and rectangle are in viewController, After dragging label into rectangle can I remove all touches in touches ended with event method.

```
touchesEnded:withEvent: {

LBL.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
 }
```

When the touches ended the user interaction should be removed from the label

Comment: here what is rectangle...?

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR rectangle is the target point in which i dragged label

Comment: means ........ur VC name is rectangle ....?

Comment: no no VC is main viewController

Comment: rectangle and labels both are in viewDidload

Comment: can u post ur code ........... its help to resolve ur issue

Comment: can we chat but my reputation is less....

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR i make labels and rectangle in viewDidLoad method using a for loop

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR okay

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR what you want to see in code ?